# Stripe: no webhook event when subscription updated

Tags: stripe-payments

## My goal

When a customer want to downgrade to a cheaper subscription, let he/she use current subscription until the end of current billing period, then switch to cheaper subscription automatically. Also I need to be notified about the change so that I can run some internal logic.

## What I have tried

I have used **subscription schedule** to schedule for price change of a subscription at the end of its current period. Using Stripe dashboard I can see that the price has been successfully changed with correct timing, but:

- There was no webhook event. I am expecting **customer.subscription.updated** event, and also tried to listen to **subscription_schedule.updated** event without success.
- The customer was not charged for the new price, even after waiting for a few hours.

Bellow are detailed steps:

- Customer subscripts to a daily price.
- Customer want to change subscription to a cheaper price.
- I create a subscription schedule from the subscription with:

```
stripe.subscriptionSchedules.create({ from_subscription: subId }).
```

- I then update the schedule with:

```
stripe.subscriptionSchedules.update(schedule.id, {
  phases: [
    {
      start_date, // billing_cycle_anchor of current subscription
      items: [
        { price: currentPriceId, quantity: 1 }, // current plan to be used until period end
      ],
      iterations: 1, // 'iterations' is set to 1, this is important because we want current phase to end at the end of current period
    },
    {
      proration_behavior: 'none', // no proration when transition to this phase
      items: [
        { price: nextPriceId, quantity: 1 }, // new plan to be switched to after current period
      ],
      iterations: 1, // 'iterations' is set to 1 and 'end_behavior' need to be set to 'release'
    },
  ],
  end_behavior: 'release', // release this schedule after last phase, so that subscription will continue as normal
});
```

**EDIT:** This strange behavior is because our Stripe Account is blacklisted due to a problem with the credit card we are using. Resolve the credit card problem and everything is back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't get an `updated` event when moving to a new phase, since the subscription technically wasn't updated.

Instead you should listen for the `invoice.created` [event](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-invoice.created). When a subscription schedule moves to a new phase it means its entering a new billing period, meaning an invoice is created.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I will try your suggestion and post result tomorrow. Normally I think either subscription updated event or schedule updated event should be fired (if not both). Stripe documentation really lacks information on these...

Comment: So I have tried your suggestion but still no luck... There was no invoice event, and verifying through Stripe Dashboard there was no invoice at all. The subscription simply got stuck after being updated with no further invoice, and no error message whatsoever.

Comment: You should write into Stripe support where they can investigate to see what happened: https://support.stripe.com/contact